# FourierSeries command , for arbitrary period T?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

```
ExptoTrig[FourierSeries[Piecewise[{{-Pi,-2Pi<x<=0},{Pi,0<x<=2Pi}}],x,3]]
```

You can see, the function goes from $(-2\pi,2\pi]$

But Wolfram Alpha gives a wrong answer to this, because she computes it as if  the function would go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

(The right answer should be $4\sin(\frac{x}{2}) + ..$.)

So, how can I use this command when the function's period T is not 2$\pi$ exactly?

Comment: Why not rescale your function first so that the function applies, and scale back after the operation?

Comment: @J.M.  I don't really know how to do that..:)

Comment: Oh we use one of the magic words of math for that: **let** $x=2u$…

Comment: @J.M. Okay, thanks:)

Comment: Did you try FourierParameters settings ?

Comment: @Lotus No, I didnt

Comment: I think FourierParameters is what you should go for, but what settings would match what you want, I do not know. Just try it out.

Comment: @Lotus Thank you, I don't know how to use it , but I will read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-Pi, -2 Pi < x <= 0}, {Pi, 0 < x <= 2 Pi}}];
T = 4 \[Pi];
fr = FourierTrigSeries[f[x], x, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 \[Pi]/T}]
(* 4 Sin[x/2] + 4/3 Sin[(3 x)/2] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow , Jesus, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @rewi.
I just write down the Wolfram Alpha version, (based on his answer). So I can remember.

```
FourierTrigSeries[Piecewise[{{-Pi, -2 Pi < x <= 0}, {Pi, 0 < x <= 2 Pi}}], x, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 1/2}]
```

where FourierParameters' second parameter is $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$